# Save pandas dataframe containing Chinese character to file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, special-characters

I have a pandas dataframe, where some fields contain Chinese character. I use the below code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('original.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df.to_csv('saved.csv')
```

Then I use excel or text editor to open saved.csv. All Chinese characters become junk characters. However, I am able to load the saved file and show the Chinese properly as follows.

```
df = pd.read_csv('saved.csv')
df.head() # Chinese characters are properly displayed.
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: does `df.to_csv('saved.csv', encoding='utf-8')` work?

Comment: In excel, you need to import the csv file, and select utf-8 as the encoding.

Comment: @EdChum It doesn't work.

Comment: @Cheng Thanks. It works. But how to make it automatic when opening such a file?

Comment: Save it as .xlsx instead of .csv. This is more of an excel issue rather than a Pandas issue.

Comment: @Cheng I tried saving it as .xlsx. 
    df.to_excel('../training_data/training_1234.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', index=None) It gave this error: IllegalCharacterError. Anything else I didn't do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try to use openpyxl: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html

Answer (score 19):

Try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('original.csv', encoding='utf-8')   
df.to_csv('saved.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

it works for me when `utf-8` failed

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the encoding of excel.

To resolve the issue, I first open the csv using sublime and then File->Save with encoding->UTF-8 with BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Now excel is able to open the csv without any problems!